# Flash player full screen control bar to large?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fullscreen

I'm developing a flash player and I have a problem with full screen mode because when  I make full screen all other elements grow larger. Any idea on fixing this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check this manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e31.html#WS0D75B487-23B9-402d-A52D-CB3C4CEB9EE4). If you attempt to set `stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE` and then request its width&height, you can then adjust your player contents to fit into the provided dimensions with proper internal scaling. This will let you control which elements are enlarged, and which will retain their size.